# sys.executable results are different in terminal and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sys

Because I face a problem: When `from imageio import imread` in my jupyter notebook, I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imageio'`
Whereas I can successfully import in my terminal, I try to figure out what happened.
When I execute `sys.executable` in jupyter notebook and in the terminal, the results are different:
[image]

[image]

So I tried:(from https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1524#issuecomment-229713719)

```
/Users/shinyuwu/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install ipykernel
/Users/shinyuwu/anaconda3/bin/python -m  ipykernel install
```

But the sys.executable result in jupyter notebook and terminal are still different. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced this issue some time back

The way I solved this was

1. Deleting IPython and Jupyter from the system
2. `rm -rf ~/.local/share/ipython`
3. Reinstall IPython and Jupyter

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In the end, I install a virtual environment in jupyter notebook and solved the inconsistency problem.

Comment: Yes creating envs is good. In my case, I had my envs created. Due to some ubuntu issues, I had to uninstall and reinstall python, anaconda and the envs. removing the ipython folder was the only thing that worked for me :)

Comment: Thanks. After messing up with a custom `venv` my `sys.executable` got changed from the conda one to the default system one. I was able to recover it by uninstall and re-install.