# sys.path and sys.executable is incorrect in jupyter, but no applied fix is working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, sys

I've configured jupyter to be used from a remote computer and set a password to it while initial anaconda setup. Then after fixing [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65359414/6701627), I am trapped in another one. `sys.path` and `sys.executable` is *incorrect* in **jupyter**, but *correct* in **python** and **ipython**. Please see the details below. Anaconda3 is installed for all users in `/opt/anaconda3` and I am using an environment `zud` for my programs.

### Background

Once the above-mentioned problem is fixed, I tried to `import igraph` in **jupyter** but it gave `ModuleNotFoundError` as below:

```
import igraph
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-73ffca960e68> in <module>
----> 1 import igraph

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'igraph'
```

Then quickly I checked the following details using my environment `zud`, which were correct.

```
(zud) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ which python
/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/bin/python
(zud) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ which ipython
/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/bin/ipython
(zud) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ which jupyter
/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/bin/jupyter
(zud) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ which conda
/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda

(zud) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
zud                   *  /home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud
base                     /opt/anaconda3
```

Then I checked `sys.path` and `sys.executable` in **python**, **ipython**, and **jupyter notebook/lab**:

**In Python:**

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python39.zip', '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9', '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
>>> sys.executable
'/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/bin/python'
```

**In ipython:**

```
**In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.path
Out[2]:
['/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/bin',
 '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python39.zip',
 '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9',
 '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/zuddler/.ipython']

In [3]: sys.executable
Out[3]: '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/bin/python'**
```

**In Jupyter Notebook/Lab:**

```
[1]: import sys
[2]: sys.path
[2]:
['/home/zuddler/python scripts',
 '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python38.zip',
 '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8',
 '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/zuddler/.ipython']
[3]: sys.executable
[3]: '/opt/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

`sys.path` and `sys.executable` were different in **Jupyter Notebook/Lab** but were correct in **Python** and **ipython**.

Also, to confirm if the current jupyter is running, I ran `!which jupyter` in the jupyter notebook and received `/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/bin/jupyter` which confirmed that the correct jupyter notebook was running.

### Tried Remedies

**Remedy 1:** I tried the fix mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50305652/6701627) and [here](https://www.lucypark.kr/blog/2013/02/10/when-python-imports-and-ipython-does-not/) and added the following line in the `/home/zuddler/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` file

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
  'import sys; sys.path.append("/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9/site-packages")'
]
```

then restarted the jupyter notebook and tried to import igraph again and got a *slightly different* `ModuleNotFoundError`

```
import igraph
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-73ffca960e68> in <module>
----> 1 import igraph

~/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9/site-packages/igraph/__init__.py in <module>
     32 # pylint: disable-msg=W0401
     33 # W0401: wildcard import
---> 34 from igraph._igraph import *
     35 from igraph.clustering import *
     36 from igraph.cut import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'igraph._igraph'
```

I quickly checked `sys.path` and `sys.executable`:

```
[1]: sys.path
[1]:
['/home/zuddler/python scripts',
 '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python38.zip',
 '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8',
 '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/zuddler/.ipython',
 '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
[2]: sys.executable
[2]: '/opt/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

It seems like a dead-end, so I rolled back this fix.

**Remedy 2:** I tried the [fix given on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57274684/6701627) and replaced the correct executable path in kernel.json

Kernels listed are:

```
(zud) zuddler@silp252-dl360:~$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

I made the following changes in `/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json`

```
{
"argv": [
```

```
"/opt/anaconda3/bin/python", "/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/bin/python",
```

```
"-m",
"ipykernel_launcher",
"-f",
"{connection_file}"
],
"display_name": "Python 3",
"language": "python"
}
```

after that, I restarted the jupyter notebook/lab and it worked for the environment `zud`, but I noticed that for the `base` environment it imported `igraph` which was not even installed in `base`. I checked the following values from them, `which jupyter` was correct for `base`

```
[1]: !which jupyter
[1]: /opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter
```

but it was picking up `sys.path` and `sys.executable` from `zud`, and that means everone will be compelled to use `zud` environment.

```
[2]: sys.path
[2]:
['/home/zuddler/python scripts',
 '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python39.zip',
 '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9',
 '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/zuddler/.ipython']
[3]: sys.executable
[3]: '/home/zuddler/.conda/envs/zud/bin/python'
```

this was again a dead end, so I rolled back this fix.

**Remedy 3:** Applying the following steps from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58466737/6701627) also did not solve the issue and gave the wrong `sys.path` and `sys.executable`

> 1. Deleting IPython and Jupyter from the system
> 2. `rm -rf ~/.local/share/ipython`
> 3. Reinstall IPython and Jupyter

**Remedy 4:** I tried opening `~/.conda/envs/zud/bin/jupyter lab --no-browser` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47655799/6701627), but it too gave wrong `sys.path` and `sys.executable`.

**Other Remedies:** I read [this](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50305652.html), but found no solution.

**PS:** I noticed that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64768368/in-jupyter-notebook-which-python-and-sys-executable-return-different-paths) is also mentioning a related issue as mine, but got no solution.

*I'll be doing more research on this in the hope to reach a solution, I'll be grateful if you could provide a solution to it.*

Answer (score 4):

I've had this issue for quite a while as well. Here's how I've solved it.

After you've created and entered the virtual environment, you probably did something like

`pip install ipykernel`

`ipython kernel install --user --name=myenv` in order to make it visible in jupyter lab/notebook.

There's this ipykernel mapping file at `/home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/myenv/kernel.json`

It should look something like this:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python3",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "language": "python",
 "display_name": "myenv"
}
```

The problem here is that the virtual env python is mapped to system python for some reason. You want to change the python pointer to point to your virtual env python, which would be similar to `/home/user/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/python3`.

TL;DR:

```
cat /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/myenv/kernel.json
```

if it has `/usr/bin/python3` in it, change it to `/home/user/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/python3`

You might need to restart your Jupyter Lab/Notebook for changes to take effect.

I don't fully understand why it sometimes happens and sometimes doesn't, but hopefully this fix will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue showed up because I didn't use `conda` to install jupyter. Adding `jupyter` and `jupyterlab` to the env.yaml file I used to generate the environment fixed it (otherwise the environment was giving access to the `base` environment's `jupyter`, with the incorrect paths associated with ti).